# Выходит ошибка в админке сайта wp woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Не пойму почему, но выходит ошибка при удаление пользователя и при некоторых других действиях. Версия  WordPress 6.4.2 с темой оформления Interio-home.Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: strlen(): Argument #1 ($str) must be of type string, array given in /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-includes/Text/Diff/.d2c9b6ba.ccss(86) : eval()'d code:4 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-includes/Text/Diff/.d2c9b6ba.ccss(86) : eval()'d code(4): hserrwne(Array) #1 /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-includes/Text/Diff/.d2c9b6ba.ccss(86): eval() #2 /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-config.php(4): include_once('/var/www/u21913...') #3 /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/var/www/u21913...') #4 /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/var/www/u21913...') #5 /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-admin/users.php(11): require_once('/var/www/u21913...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/u2191356/data/www/interio-home.shop/wp-includes/Text/Diff/.d2c9b6ba.ccss(86) : eval()'d code on line 4
```

Comment: Тема не работает с PHP8+. И вообще имеет плохой код, раз подсовывает массив вместо строки.